# Spritekit collisions between arrays of SpriteNodes

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game that involves a number of Sprite Arrays and I want to detect collisions between them and specify functions depending on which etc.

So say I have an array of 16 balls ballArray[I] and 16 blocks blockaArray[I] which I can easily iterate through using the index number I.

I have given the balls a Physics Category - Balls and similar to for Blocks. Then I have 16 ID Physics categories say ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4

So I can detect a collision, know that is was a Ball hitting a Block but I then need to know which ball and which block.

What the best or easiest way to do this? I'm reading about enumerateChildNodes(withName) function but have not used it. Or can I create array of PhysicsCategories which I could iterate through along with the SpriteArray to compare and identify.

EDIT:

Thanks Everyone for the help. I have finally cracked it. Surprisingly in the end the code a lot simpler than I first thought. Still not fully understanding where the bits are sitting in my categories but have it working .

I'll try to post my final working code - you may have suggestions to improve. Many thanks again and apologies for my poor StackFlow etiquette - I am new here :-)

So my Physics Categories were defined.

```
struct PhysicsCategories {
    static let BoxCategoryMask = UInt32(1<<7)
    static let BallCategoryMask = UInt32(1<<8)

}
```

and then in my function to build an array of Sprites

```
boxBloqArray[i].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.BoxCategoryMask | UInt32(i)              
boxBloqArray[i].physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.BallCategoryMask
```

and the same for the ball array but just the categoryBitMask

```
 ballBloqArray[i].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.BallCategoryMask | UInt32(i)
```

I'm still not really sure why it has to be this way round but that was the final problem this evening that I had the two bodies the wrong way round in the && comparison in the final working detection code:

```
var body1 = SKPhysicsBody()
   var body2 = SKPhysicsBody()

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            body1 = contact.bodyA
            body2 = contact.bodyB
        }
        else {
            body1 = contact.bodyB
            body2 = contact.bodyA
        }


        // Check node collisions
        for n in 0...15 {
            for i in 0...15 {
                if body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.BallCategoryMask | UInt32(n) && body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.BoxCategoryMask | UInt32(i) {
                    //if body1.node != nil {
                       print("Ball\(n) hit Box\(i)")
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
```

and that is now printing the correct collisions.... lovely!... onwards to 
the next step... thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't need to loop over `i` and `n`, just `let n = Int(body2.categoryBitMask & 0xf)` and similarly for `i`, but anyway glad it's working.

Comment: Ok thats smart. So the & 0xf just removes the relevant bit for the category and leaves the remaining integer? Amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the two nodes involved in the collision as discussed in the answer by @Luca Angeletti, you can turn those into an index in various ways.

1. If you've made each type of node a specialized subclass and you have the appropriate indexes stored as class members, then you can convert to the appropriate class and look at the index fields, e.g.,

```swift
if let block = nodeA as? BlockNode, let ball = nodeB as? BallNode {
  print("block \(block.blockIndex) hit ball \(ball.ballIndex)")
}
```

2. Nodes are hashable, so you can have dictionaries to map them back to indexes:

```swift
if let blockIndex = blockIndexes[nodeA], let ballIndex = ballIndexes[nodeB] {
  print("block \(blockIndex) hit ball \(ballIndex)")
}
```

3. You can use the `userData` property of nodes to store whatever you like, including the indexes.  The mucking around with NS things gets kind of ugly though.
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483121-userdata
4. You can do the linear scan through each array.

```swift
if let blockIndex = blocks.firstIndex(of: nodeA), let ballIndex = balls.firstIndex(of: nodeB) {
  print("block \(blockIndex) hit ball \(ballIndex)")
}
```

5. It sounds like from your question that you might have a separate category bit mask for each individual block and each individual ball.  Or if you don't, that is possible if there are at most 16 of each.  Anyway, if that's the case, then you can do some bit flicking to take the categoryBitMask from the physics bodies, shift the ball/block one by 16 bits (whichever is using the high bits gets shifted), and then take log2 of the bit masks to get your indexes.  You can find various bit flicking techniques for log2 here:
   https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Given 16 things of each type, I'd say just do #4.  If you already have subclass nodes, #1 is fine.  Number 2 is spreading state around a bit, so I'm not such a fan of that.  Number 3 I would not really recommend because of the NS stuff.  Number 5 is too cute for its own good.

Edit: Now that I read again, it sounds like maybe you've got separate ID's for categories 1...16, so your block category bit masks are like:
`blockCategoryMask | ID1`, `blockCategoryMask | ID2`, etc.  That can also work (basically a variant of #5).  If you're going down that route though, you may as well just stick the index directly into the category masks:

```swift
let blockCategoryMask = UInt32(1<<4)
let ballCategoryMask = UInt32(1<<5)
```

Then the physics body for a block gets mask `blockCategoryMask | UInt32(index)`, and similarly for a ball.  In that case the index extraction is just `categoryBitMask & UInt32(0xf)`.  Or if you put the block and ball categories in bits 0 and 1 and the indexes in bits 2-5, then right shift by 2 to get the index.

Edit in response to comment:
OK, so let's take the case of 6 distinct categories of objects, and each object can fall into one of 16 distinct subcategories.  To be able to control which contacts are reported, you'd assign a bit mask to each of the 6 main categories:

```swift
enum Category: UInt32 {
  // Basic categories
  case block =    0b000001
  case ball =     0b000010
  case shot =     0b000100
  case obstacle = 0b001000
  case wizard =   0b010000
  case food =     0b100000
 }
```

Since you've used 6 bits for the main category, you have 26 bits remaining.  To encode the 16 subcategories needs 4 bits.  You can put those in the category bit mask above the main 6 bits.  Example manipulations:

```swift
func encodeObject(category: Category, subcategory: Int) -> UInt32 {
  return category.rawValue | (UInt32(subcategory) << 6)
}

func nodeIsA(node: SKNode, category: Category) -> Bool {
  guard let body = node.physicsBody else { return false }
  return (body.categoryBitMask & category.rawValue) != 0
}

func subcategory(node: SKNode) -> Int {
  guard let body = node.physicsBody else { fatalError("missing physicsbody") }
  return Int(body.categoryBitMask >> 6)
}
```

Note that the subcategories are just sort of tagging along for the ride; all your contactBitMasks would deal only to the main categories.

Essentially you're using the fact that you've got some extra bits in the physics body category bit masks to just store random information.  I've done that before with simple sprites.  But if the information needed is going to get any more complex that a simple number or index, I'd recommend making subclasses of nodes rather than trying to squirrel stuff away in the unused bits.

Comment: wow ok. Think you have the right answer there but I just need to understand it! Indeed there are 6 major categories and then up to 26 sub categories. So I can in theory detect hits between 156 types of collisions. Your very final explanation looks to me how I should do it but I don't really understand how that code puts the index directly into the Cat Bit mask.?

The other route I thought to try was by naming SpriteNodes-  ie name = "block\(i)". But then not sure how id iterate though that as physics categories anyway

Comment: thanks again bg2b. Well in the words of Buffalo Springfield, there's something happening here what it is ain't exactly clear... I've only been coding with Swift for about 6-7 weeks now so this concept is hurting my brain -  a lot. So I thought I'd just chuck in the code you suggested and try to make some sense of it. Surprisingly it actually does something almost as I wanted but far from perfect. I'd like to post the code I have and more explanation here but don't have the room.. and posting in the answer section where there IS room seems to upset everyone... new to StackOverflow also...

Comment: You can edit the original question to stick updated code at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using `contact.bodyA.node` and `contact.bodyB.node` you can get the `SKNode(s)` which are involved in the contact

```
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        switch (contact.bodyA.node, contact.bodyB.node) {
        case (let ball as Ball, let block as Block):
            didBeginContactBetween(ball: ball, andBlock: block)
        case (let block as Block, let ball as Ball):
            didBeginContactBetween(ball: ball, andBlock: block)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func didBeginContactBetween(ball: Ball, andBlock block: Block) {
        // TODO: put your code here
    }

}
```